# how to get fbId of any fb page in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook

I am trying to get the fbid of our user's profile to generate the fb://page/fbid

below I have attached my function findFacebookId() to get the fbid and it works for all FB page URLs except the URL is in capital form

for example

https://www.facebook.com/userpage - findFacebookId() return the fbId for this url

https://www.facebook.com/UserPage - findFacebookId() will not work for this url

**Note:** on my local terminal it do not ask to login but when I run this function on my ubuntu server it asks to log in

```
findFacebookId: (name,cb) => {
    const curl = new (require('curl-request'))();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let url = `https://www.facebook.com/${name}`;
      curl.setHeaders([
        'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'
      ]).get(url)
        .then(({ statusCode, body, headers }) => {
          var regularExpresionMatch = /fb:\/\/(group|page|profile)\/(\d{1,})/gi;
          const matches = body.match(regularExpresionMatch)
          const oldmatches = body.match(/entity_id":"\d*/i);
          if (matches && matches.length > 0) {
            const id = matches[0];
            cb(null,id);
            return;
          } else {
            cb(true)
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          cb(e);
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Scraping Facebook is not allowed. Even if you get this to work right now, expect them to block your server IP once they get wise to what you are doing. Also, Facebook has _deliberately_ made it harder for apps to link to user profiles (requires asking the user for permission, and will generate a link that will only worked for logged-in users, that are friends with the profile owner) - so you should probably not even _try_ this in the first place.

Comment: I see, a great explanation, I also do not want to use this method. so, can you please explain to me how to get the fbid from FB graph API

Comment: For user profiles - not at all any more. All you get is an app-scoped user id, and that can't be used to link to their profile. The `link` field with a tokenized URL is all you can get, but that will only work in a browser, and for friends of the user. For pages, you'd have to ask the user for permission to access the pages they are an admin of; for pages you/they got no admin access to, you would need the Page Public Metadata Access feature approved for your app first.